# Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x

Tags: arrays, linux-kernel, kernel-module, ioctl

While working on kernel modules, I have been facing this issue when passing an array from kernel space to user space.

I am using IOCTL call in userspace to get the array from the kernel space

```c
ret_val = ioctl(filedes, IOCTL_PRINT, localarray);
```

And copy_to_user to pass it from kernel to user space.

```c
ret = copy_to_user((int *)ioctl_param, kernel_array, 15 * sizeof(int));
```

This is my error

```auto
[  461.909674] Data value in index 0 : 21
[  461.909678] Data value in index 1 : 20
[  461.909678] Data value in index 2 : 19
[  461.909679] Data value in index 3 : 18
[  461.909680] Data value in index 4 : 17
[  461.909681] Data value in index 5 : 16
[  461.909681] Data value in index 6 : 15
[  461.909682] Data value in index 7 : 14
[  461.909683] Data value in index 8 : 13
[  461.909683] Data value in index 9 : 12
[  461.909684] Data value in index 10 : 11
[  461.909737] Data value in index 11 : 10
[  461.909738] Data value in index 12 : 9
[  461.909739] Data value in index 13 : 8
[  461.909740] Data value in index 14 : 7
[  461.910279] io[1799]: segfault at c0000000d ip 0000000c0000000d sp 00007fffaa57cd40 error 14 in         io[556f58436000+1000]
[  461.910288] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0xbffffffe3.
```

When I run it I could get the Kernel log but I cannot pass my array in the userspace. Is there a problem in pointer dereferencing?

Comment: How is `localarray` declared? If it is a pointer rather than an array, is it pointing to something valid that can store 15*4 bytes (15 `int`s)?

Comment: Localarray is declared as a normal array of integers and not as a array of pointers or as a pointer.

Comment: please show a [mre]